# How to add extra filters to a existing Acumatica page

Tags: acumatica

Good day,

Every vendor and customer will be linked to an Employee that is responsible for them.

I need to add an extra filter on the "Calculate Overdue Charges" Page, AR507000, this will be linking back to the customers and only showing the Employees
[image]

What is the current place to add the code to add this extra filter?
Does anyone have an example or article I can find more info on?

I did figure out how to do this but I am not sure if is the best way

Answer (score 0):

First, find the method that does the calculation/Filter in mycase it is CalculateFinancialCharges

2de add your logic under the normal baseMethod and remove needed items using Remove(item);

```
 public delegate void CalculateFinancialChargesDelegate(ARFinChargesApplyParameters filter);
                [PXOverride]
                public void CalculateFinancialCharges(ARFinChargesApplyParameters filter, CalculateFinancialChargesDelegate baseMethod)
                {
               
                    baseMethod(filter);
                
                    try
                    {
                        ARFinChargesApplyParameters curARFinChargesApplyParameters = this.Base.Filter.Current;
                        ARFinChargesApplyParametersExt curARFinChargesApplyParametersExt = curARFinChargesApplyParameters.GetExtension<ARFinChargesApplyParametersExt>();
        
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(curARFinChargesApplyParametersExt.UsrEmployeeID))
                        {
        
                            foreach (ARFinChargesDetails item in this.Base.ARFinChargeRecords.Cache.Inserted)
                            {
                                BAccount bAccount = PXSelect<Customer,
                                    Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Required<ARFinChargesDetails.customerID>>>>.
                                    Select(Base, item.CustomerID);
                                BAccountExt bAccountExt = bAccount.GetExtension<BAccountExt>();
        
                                if (bAccountExt.UsrEmployeeID != curARFinChargesApplyParametersExt.UsrEmployeeID)
                                {

                                    this.Base.ARFinChargeRecords.Cache.Remove(item);
                                }
        
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                       PXTrace.WriteError(ex);
            
                    }
        
    }
```